# How can I use the batchupdate function of the google form api with python to modify the url and answers?

Tags: python, google-forms-api

Here is an example of my form. How can I use python to modify the url and answer for the first question, as I am not familiar with using batchupdate?

I can use "get" to retrieve information from the form.

```
{'formId': '1q4pJMDtiLxQ2cjmLXxowqJ5VPfI68bUUo', 
'info': {'title': 'PIXEL ', 'documentTitle': 'daily'}, 
'settings': {'quizSettings': {'isQuiz': True}},
 'revisionId': '00000067', 
'responderUri': 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScap6ZdpOnWIyxWqZNXjlfWW9DgPe-Wv_CUtziWw/viewform', 
'items': [{'itemId': '7c0ddb37', 'pageBreakItem': {}}, 
        {'itemId': '2870b06c', 'videoItem': {'video': {'youtubeUri': 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt5HqPvM-eI', 'properties': {'alignment': 'LEFT', 'width': 320}}}},
        {'itemId': '381aedf6', 'questionGroupItem': {'questions': [{'questionId': '4d7f011e', 'required': True, 'rowQuestion': {'title': 'pick'}}], 'grid': {'columns': {'type': 'RADIO',         'options': [{'value': '1'}, {'value': '2'}, {'value': '3'}]}}}, 'title': 'pay'}, 
          {'itemId': '0f9dc00b', 'title': 'number', 'questionItem': {'question': {'questionId': '39523976', 'required': True, 
          'grading': {'correctAnswers': {'answers': [{'value':'1115'}]}}, 'textQuestion': {}}}}, 
          {'itemId': '0a12a42e', 'pageBreakItem': {}}, 
          {'itemId': '19640fea', 'videoItem': {'video': {'youtubeUri': 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt5HqPvM-eI', 'properties': {'alignment': 'LEFT', 'width': 320}}}}, 
          {'itemId': '685ba545', 'questionGroupItem': {'questions': [{'questionId': '044f9f9b', 'required': True, 'rowQuestion': {'title': 'pick'}}], 'grid': {'columns': {'type': 'RADIO',           'options': [{'value': '1'}, {'value': '2'}, {'value': '3'}]}}}, 'title': 'pay'}, 
          {'itemId': '6a9d1b88', 'title': 'number', 'questionItem': {'question': {'questionId': '2199beb0', 'required': True, 
            'grading': {'correctAnswers': {'answers': [{'value': '1115'}]}}, 'textQuestion': {}}}}]}
```

The official documentation has too few examples for me to understand how to apply it to my form.

```
update = {
    "requests": [{
        "updateItem": {
            "item": {
                "title": "Homework video",
                "description": "Quizzes in Google Forms",
                "videoItem": {
                    "video": {
                        "youtubeUri": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt5HqPvM-eI"
                    }
                }
            },"location": {
                "index": 0},
            "updateMask": "description,youtubeUri"
        }
    }]
}

question_setting = service.forms().batchUpdate(
    formId=form_id, body=update).execute()
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `modify the url and answer for the first question` from your question. And, in your showing script, it seems that you want to create a new item. But in your question, you say `modify the url and answer for the first question`. So, I cannot understand your expected result. I apologize for this. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: @Tanaike  I have to apologize for my poor English skill,I used a translation software.
I want to update the youtubeUri item and use a new URL. How can I do this? i have two question use the video,how do i  update the first question URL ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike  Thank you for resolving my question!!!  it works .   May I ask you another question? If I want to update the correct short answer and use response validation. may i also update it too?or only can update the correct answer .What should I do?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `May I ask you another question?`, I would like to support you. But your new question is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question? Because when your initial question is changed by a comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes I understand. Thank you. I will post a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I found your new question, I would like to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I want to update the youtubeUri item and use a new URL. How can I do this? i have two question use the video,how do i update the first question URL ?

I understood your question is as follows.

- You want to update `youtubeUri` of 1st question in Google Forms using googleapis for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
service =   # Please use your client

formId = "###" # Please set your Google Form ID.
after = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=###" # Please set YouTube URL you want to replace. In this sample, the existing URL is changed to this URL.

res = service.forms().get(formId=formId).execute()
itemIds = [[i, e["itemId"]] for i, e in enumerate(res.get("items")) if "videoItem" in e]
topItem = itemIds[0] # From your question, `youtubeUri` of the 1st question.
req = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateItem": {
                "item": {
                    "itemId": topItem[1],
                    "videoItem": {
                        "video": {
                            "youtubeUri": after,
                        }
                    },
                },
                "location": {"index": topItem[0]},
                "updateMask": "videoItem.video.youtubeUri",
            }
        }
    ]
}
service.forms().batchUpdate(formId=formId, body=req).execute()
```

- When this script is run, first, all items are retrieved. And, the item IDs including `youtubeUri` are retrieved. And, using the 1st item ID, the value of `youtubeUri` is changed to the value of `after` you set.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that you have already been able to get and out values to Google Form using Google Form API. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: forms.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/batchUpdate)